# Too little water in concrete

Tags: concrete

A few days back, after I had finished work at my day job, I decided to pour a slab of concrete for my home's walkway, but did so hurriedly.

I had originally planned to do it later during the weekend, but I was anxious to beat the incoming rain, and head off any complaints from my partner about bags of concrete sitting around.

My first few pours, before my eyes had adjusted to the dark, were *way too* dry, but I brushed it off as *better too little than too much water*! I'm sure a few of my subsequent pours will have some extra water to donate.

Today, I stripped off the molds and my worries of too little water were validated. The top of the slab looks smooth, but the bottom layer looks a bit cratery.

Is there anything I can do to save the slab? Am I worried over nothing?

Comment: Now that is down there is nothing you can do but keep it wet until it is cured. Really soak it down morning and night have water pudding on it. The edge craters can happen even with a wet pour.

Comment: I have been lightly spraying the top almost every hour almost religiously since 4 hours after I finished the pour. Been spraying the sides too since I took the mold off. It was solid almost right away (I used a very little amount of water). I am mostly worried long term

Comment: The bottom is not "cratery" because of too little water, it is because of lack of getting the concrete to coalesce usually via vibration. Further, you may not have hydrated all of the cement; when we manually mix, we have to put the cement into the water FIRST, thenw e add the sand and gravel otherwise it is almost ipossible to get all the cement to hydrate properly.  As a note  4" (seems dry) +/- slump is usually good for structural concrete.  Most people pour between 6-8+" (nice and flowy) slump which weakens the concrete.

Comment: @Damon I used too little water considering I was not using a vibrator ;)